# Possible to view simplified or optimized SQL query for a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

Given an ugly and probably long, inefficient, redundant and complicated looking query, is there a tool that can simplify that for a target database?  If not, since the database optimizes queries anyway, is it possible to see the optimized query that the database will use?  I'm not interested in the actual query plan but rather the optimized and/or simplified query.  Is that possible?  I'm interested in answers for any of these databases: MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, SQLite.

Comment: By design, SQL expresses the logic of a query independently of whatever query plan might be used to execute it. So although there is such a thing as a simplified query, to a first approximation there's not really such thing as an "optimized" SQL query. Of course, in practice most DBs let you stuff in forcing clauses like USE INDEX, but that's usually best avoided since it prevents the DB from adjusting to changing data profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since the database optimizes queries anyway ...

**PostgreSQL** optimizes the query plan, but that hardly translates to a corresponding SQL query. It's not the SQL code itself that get re-written. So, *no*, you cannot derive an optimized SQL query form the optimized query plan unless you have very deep understanding of the inner workings of the query planner.

You can find out whether indexes get used or the query planner chooses a table scan instead and other helpful details by looking at the output of [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html).

Comment: The same answer holds true for MySQL. You see the query plan with EXPLAIN EXTENDED, but it's in a tabular form that requires some knowledge to interpret rather than in the form of a query.